# Liferay Primefaces Portlet redirection issue

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, portlet, liferay-6

I am currently creating a primfaces portlet. From my view.xhtml when I am calling Submit method in my bean class. I want to redirect the view base on input.

Below is my code snippet of Submit method:

```
Submit(){
try {
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/views/Success.xhtml");
} catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

It simply adds to the local host URL as `http://localhost:8081/views/Success.xhtml`. I guess I am missing something critical probably. Should implement some render phase method if yes how do i go about it so that it created a render url for that page.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using normal JSF navigation for this? No need to bother with portlet URLs in that case, because it will be handled by the JSF bridge for you.

```
public String submit() {
    // do stuff;
    return "/views/Success";
}
```

You can omit the `.xhtml` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the url using the following code

```
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext
            .getRequest();

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) req.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    PortletURL url = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(req, 
            PortalUtil.getPortletId(req),
            themeDisplay.getLayout().getPlid(), 
            PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);
    url.setParameter("_facesViewIdRender", "/views/Success.xhtml");
    url.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
    url.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url.toString());
```